# Django : How to rollback changes done to the database depending on some condition?

Tags: django, django-models, webserver

I have to rollback the changes done to the database depending on some condition, but up to that 'some condition' the changes should be reflected in the database for other users.

```
@transaction.atomic
def populate_db(input):
  Object = Table.objects.select_for_update().get(attributeX=input)
  Object.attributeY = False
  Object.save()

  ** some operation here **
```

Problem I'm facing is, the value of attributeY is not getting stored in the database until the whole function is executed successfully, but what i want is changed value of attributeY should be reflected in database until **some operation** fails.

And I cannot get to know whether **some operation** is failed or not, because the failures I'm trying to handle here are closing browser accidentally, power outage kind of things.

Any help is appreciated, thanks !

Comment: It appears that your definition of "Transaction" is contradictory. You want transaction roll-back if some later operation fails, but you want attribute Y to commit immediately. You have to pick one or the other.

Comment: Okay, my bad. It would be a common problem for a ticket booking website. Suppose a movie slot is currently being booked and the user is in payment page. At this time, other users should see this slot as booked(attributeY). But in case the currently booking user closes the browser window/power outage, tcp connection is lost and the thread will be killed, so even though transaction has failed, the slot will remain as booked. So, is there any other way to handle above specified failure scenarios ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what would `populate_db` see that indicates the transaction did not complete?

For example, the seat has been reserved but not yet paid for (because of fault). In this case, `populate_db` should not complete the transaction until it also has a payment authorization code.

Alternately, if you want to mark the seat's status as `being_reserved`, then there is no transaction, the status gets set to `being_reserved` and other clients can see it. In this model, `populate_db` would be responsible for detecting the fault (through exceptions possibly) and returning the seat status to `available` in another database update.

The error in your thinking is that the database can remain consistent regardless of the failure of any component. That requirement cannot be satisfied. You cannot both allow other clients to see `being_reserved` and suffer a failure of `populate_db`.

This trade-off is central to every reservation system ever written. And there are too many ways to regain consistency in the face of arbitrary failure to enumerate here.